# How to resolve npm start errors and what do they mean?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am attempting to view a pre-established React.js project for a coding bootcamp. I am receiving this message on my PC while attempting to start React (npm start).

```
npm audit fix
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path D:\[Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\[Projects-React]\bey-slay\node_modules\.bin\handlebars
npm ERR! Refusing to delete D:\[Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\[Projects-React]\bey-slay\node_modules\.bin\handlebars: is outside D:\[Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\[Projects-React]\bey-slay\node_modules\handlebars and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: D:\[Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\[Projects-React]\bey-slay\node_modules\.bin\handlebars
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\imcke\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-02T14_24_44_795Z-debug.log

D:\[Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\[Projects-React]\bey-slay>npm start

> bey-slay@0.1.0 start D:\[Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\[Projects-React]\bey-slay
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bey-slay@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bey-slay@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\imcke\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-02T14_50_37_378Z-debug.log

D:\[Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\[Projects-React]\bey-slay>
```

Comment: Did you do npm install before ?

Comment: What audit problem were you trying to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have react-scripts installed (`npm i react-scripts`).

If you just downloaded a full react project, please run `npm install` before running `npm start`. If it is still not working you might have to install the dev Dependencies as well (react-scripts is a dev Dependency) `npm install --only=dev`